# Java ball moving

Tags: java, line

My problem is that the ball turns into a line once moved.
Here is the code:

```
package Java;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class javagame extends JFrame {

    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbg;

    int x, y;

    public class AL extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {

            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if(keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
                x-= 5;
            }
            if(keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
                x+= 5;
            }
            if(keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
                y-= 5;
            }
            if(keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
                y+= 5;
            }
        }
        public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e) {
        }
    }

    public javagame() {
        addKeyListener(new AL());

        setTitle("Java Game");
        setSize(750, 750);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        x = 250;
        y = 250;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        paintCompenent(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Copy Right All rights reserved to Aaron Collins 2013-2013", 275, 100);
        g.drawLine(270, 105, 415, 105);

        g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);

        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new javagame();
    }
}
```

When I say it turns into a line, I mean the ball moves but does not remove the previous one.
Please help me resolve the problem so I can continue with my game!

Comment: This code does not compile. Is it the actual code you are using?

Comment: yes... Im using eclipse

Comment: There is no `paintCompenent` method, so I question the line `paintCompenent(dbg);`. And if that line has been altered from the original, what else has been altered?

Comment: I don't know if it compiles with anything else than eclipse

Comment: You'd probably get more mileage out of a pre-made game engine like Libgdx http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Comment: I don't Know... I just followed the youtube video

Comment: are you sure that I didn't make the paintCompenent method?

Comment: I'm just saying that the code here is not the exact code you are running. There are no two ways about it. `paintCompEnent` (with an e) != `paintCompOnent` (with an o). Perhaps I sound too picky to you. But as I mentioned above, an error in one part calls the whole thing into question. Too often people hand-write what they *think* is the distilled version of their code, but it turns out to be different in some critical way and so we can't give them any help.

Comment: oh... that explains a lot. So I just have to fix the spelling?

Comment: thanks for the vital information!

Comment: I DON'T KNOW (please pardon the caps). All I know about your code is that if it actually runs (and you said it does), then it is not what you have posted here.

Comment: wait! Now the program won't launch now!

Comment: here is the error code: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at Java.javagame.main(Java Game.java:103)

Comment: please help me get it lauching!

Comment: Look for the little red squiggly underlines in Eclipse; each of them should say what is wrong at that spot.

Comment: yay! i clicked on the red squiggly line and it told me an option! When I took it, it fixed it all!

Comment: I'm curious who makes these tutorials? I always recognize them for two reasons: 1) Dissrespecting naming conventions; 2) That `AL` class which extends KeyAdapter.

Comment: @brano88 The Java Hub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You override `paint`, but never call `super.paint`, meaning that component never prepares the Graphics context for a new paint cycle, meaning that what ever you painted before remains
2. Your `paintComponent` method will never be called because `JFrame` does not support this method
3. You should not be performing custom painting on a top level container (like `JFrame`), but should be using something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method (making sure you call `super.paintComponent` first).
4. You should also avoid calling any method that may trigger a repaint in any `paintXxx` method you're overriding...like `repaint`

The `Graphics` context is a shared resource, that means that the `Graphics` context you are given was used to paint all the other components in UI before you.  `paintComponent` is responsible for preparing the `Graphics` context for painting by clearing the area it wants to paint in.

I'd recommend that you take a read through [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

I would also avoid `KeyListener` and use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.

Comment: yes but I already talked it out with another person and fixed it. But thanks for the info.